# Converting mac edited .tex file into unix compatible

Tags: macos, unix, latex

I have some problem with porting .tex files edited and created in mac os into unix. I have created some .tex files, my professor wants to commit something on it. I use ubuntu, he uses mac os. When he passes some comments, the line number of tex files changes to 1. How could I fix it and the character  `^M`  is added in the tex file. Is there any tool to make it compatible in unix?

Comment: Use `dos2unix` or `unix2dos` to convert, it seems to be a matter of newlines.

Comment: Also, are you sure it's an `M` and not `^M`?